# How to say "I did that because I was forced to do it"

Tags: phrases

Is there a phrase to use in this sentence: "I did that because I was forced to do it (by someone / by circumstances)".

Comment: "I had to do it ".  It means you had no choice.

Comment: I did it under duress.

Comment: You need to say what you had to do, and the risk if you didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [coerce](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coerce)
>   : to make (someone) do something by using force or threats
>   : to get (something) by using force or threats

*I did that because I was coerced (into doing it).*

If you're looking for some expressions, then

1. [force someone's hand](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/force+someone%27s+hand)
   Compel someone to act or speak prematurely or against his or her will.
2. [twist (someone's) arm](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/twist+arm)
   To pressure or coerce

might work.